# JavaScript: variable declaration, at run-time and parse-time are different between browser and nodejs? Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, express

Just want to be 100% percent sure I got this. Why this happens? 
Please take a look at the following console prints. The output should be the same but is not.

**Node console.**

```
// ReferenceError: foo is not defined
// I'm a, A can be printed!
// ReferenceError: b is not defined
```

**Browser console.**

```
// I'm foo
// I'm a, A can be printed!
// I'm b, B can be printed!
```

Now the code. This code is suppose to do exactly the same thing on both consoles.

Node **main.js** :

```
function foo(){
  console.log("I'm foo!");
}
a = "I'm a";
var b = "I'm b";
require("/remoteFile")(); // this calls the function inside the remoteFile which internally calls foo(), and the console.logs of a and b.
```

Node **remoteFile.js** :

```
module.exports = function(){ 
    //console.log("Remote file loaded!");
    foo()
    console.log(a, "A can be printed!"); 
    console.log(b, "B can be printed!");
}
```

Browser code:
**index.html:**

```
<script>
    function foo(){
       console.log("I'm foo!");
    }
    a = "I'm a.";
    var b = "I'm b."
</script>
<script src="/addRemoteJavascript.js"></script>
```

**addRemoteJavascript.js :**

```
(function(){ 
    //console.log("Remote file loaded!");
    foo();
    console.log(a, "A can be printed!");
    console.log(b, "B can be printed!");
})(); // this functions will run as soon as it's loaded.
```

Because all 3 variables: `foo`, `a`, `b` ware declared outside of any function, I tend to consider them global variables.

In Browser `This variables` can be called/ used from whatever file I want - because are global. Once the file is loaded by the src attributes `this variables,` can, and will be *used directly by the code* inside the external file. This is my understanding now. This in Node, doesn't hold true.

Question:

Why `a` is accessible from the remote file but the `foo function` is not?

I want to know especially how the `run-time` and `parse-time` process rely happens in node - i mean if this compiling process is rely done on each file individually - how then everything is but back together in the `app.js` and calculated there? What is actually happening?

Can or can not see the app.js script as a huge immense script which is pulled form the multiple files and run at the same time line by line?

Thank you for taking the time to read, rate and respond to this question.

Comment: The concept of "passes" is not part of the language spec and is not necessarily how any particular environment works. Variable declaration and variable initialization are separate concepts; initialization is just like a simple assignment expression statement. Other than that, it's hard to tell what question you're asking.

Comment: What's unclear about this question? OP could you remove that wall of text and focus on the topic, tjen I'm sure this question can be reopened and I will remove my downvotw.

Comment: @Tomáš Zato no problem. Thanks for assistance.I'm just trying to do my best to explain this situation. If this is still not good hmm.. maybe it does not matter. I will remove this question completely and try again after i understand more about what i need to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In

   ```
   var x = 0;
   ```

   there are two parts: the variable declaration, and the initialization. It is interpreted exactly the same as if it were written:

   ```
   var x; x = 0;
   ```
2. When a JavaScript source file is imported into a browser via a `<script>` tag, the script is evaluated in the global context, so `var` declarations outside of functions create global variables. In the browser, global variables are properties of the global `window` object. In Node.js, things are different: modules are evaluated in a non-global per-module context, so `var` declarations outside of functions *do not* create truly global variables.